# Error in addInputPath of MapReduce Driver

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-plugins

I am getting the error in the addInputPath method of my MapReduce Driver.
The error is

```
"The method addInputPath(Job, Path) in the type FileInputFormat is not applicable for the arguments (JobConf, Path)"
```

Here is my code for the driver:

```
package org.myorg;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool{
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
          //creating a JobConf object and assigning a job name for identification purposes
          JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), org.myorg.WordCount.class);
          conf.setJobName("WordCount");

          //Setting configuration object with the Data Type of output Key and Value
          conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
          conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

          //Providing the mapper and reducer class names
          conf.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
          conf.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

          //the hdfs input and output directory to be fetched from the command line
          **FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));**
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

          JobClient.runJob(conf);
          return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
          int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new WordCount(),args);
          System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

I import the correct org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.

My WordCountMapper correctly implements Mapper.

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath works correctly.

Why does the addInputhPaths throw an error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing the old API (`.mapred.`) and the new API (`.mapreduce.`). The two APIs are not compatible.

I suggest you use all the objects from the new API and not use anything from the old API.  That is, don't use `JobConf` or `JobClient`. Use `Job` and `Configuration` instead. And be sure you are using `Mapper`, `Reducer`, etc. from an import that includes `.mapreduce.` *not* `.mapred.`.

Comment: Thank you.There is too much confusion all around with regard to this. This clears it up.

Comment: For the most part I completely ignore the existence of the old API.